# Docusign - using two different email body/blurb contents

Tags: html, email, docusignapi, branding

Hello I have setup our app using the dev/demo account and almost ready to get a paid account. I want to get a starter API account, which doesn't have Branding.

1. Can I remove the Resource File from the email body without having access to branding? Any other way?
2. I would like to setup one email body/blurb for the signing email and a different for the completed email. Again without branding would I be able to do that?

I have been able to add customize/add html into the signing email body but would like to add a new condition somehow for the completed

something like envDef.EmailBlurbCompleted =

thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's only one **emailBlurb** field in DocuSign right now. That field is used in both the original as well as the final email that are sent out. You can customize it per recipient, which is not exactly what you're asking for.

You can change it after the envelope is created, but only if it's still in **draft** status.

Changing this field when an envelope is in sent status requires a [correct operation](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-correct-documents). Which is also not exactly what you are asking to do.

At the moment what you're asking is not a feature that exist, you can build something to mimic this, but I'm not sure that is a good idea either.